grab router link anchor id with Vue Router and Vue Composition API
Using vue-router v4 with Vue v3 Composition api how to I get the id of the generated anchor tag when clicked? This is for analytics tagging usage.
Example usage:
<RouterLink id="linkHome" to="/home">home</RouterLink>
<RouterLink id="linkLogo" to="/home"><svg>.... </svg></RouterLink>

I think I need beforeRouteLeave to access this. But according to the docs when the Composition API is used:
// same as beforeRouteLeave option but with no access to this
here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api
How can I read the id of the clicked route link on click?
I tried to work with beforeRouteLeave but I am not sure of the syntax between older and the newest version of Vue.

It's unclear how you intend to use linkLogo. This looks like XY problem. RouterLink is mostly the same as <a href="link" @click="$router.push('link')">. If you want to behave it in some other way, create your own component or a wrapper for RouterLink

I'm pretty sure, whatever you want to achieve with link id you can achieve with route meta props and navigation guards. It would be much easier if you would say, what exactly you want to achieve!

How can I read the id attribute of the clicked route anchor tag on click? I want to use the id in a call to an analytics vendor to track clicks. The id is used a unique identifier for each click. I think I am going to wrap  with a new component. thanks @EstusFlask

@WilliamShackelford Needs to be read from mouse event, it won't be available in beforeRouteLeave etc. Would probably be<RouterLink @click="trackId($event.target.id)" ...> for brevity. You need to refer the implementation in using a comp in an unconventional way. Here https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/RouterLink.ts#L282-L284 it appears that your click handler that falls through to  won't override RouterLink's own handler, which is undocumented but reliable vue behaviour, I believe
